# Buscar un elemento en una base de datos MongoDB usando Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Muy bien, acá tengo un código donde tengo mi servidor Express, la conexión a la base de datos y al parecer todo funciona bien.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/firulais', { useNewUrlParser: true }, ()=> {
  console.log("Connected")
});

//Models
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', {
  id:String,
  first:String,
  last:String,
  age:Number,
  pass:String,
  country:String,
  tel:Number,
  adm:Boolean
})


var Polls = mongoose.model('Polls', {
  id:String,
  name:String,
  description:String,
  yes:Number,
  no:Number,
  veto:Boolean
})

var a = Users.find({
  tel:7862627420
})
console.log(a.tel)
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(helmet());


app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.render("index")

})

app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.render("index")

})

app.post('/reglas', (req,res)=>{
  var tel = req.body.number;
  var pass = req.body.password;

})
module.exports = app;
```

La parte que me preocupa es cuando voy a buscar algún dato en alguna colección de la base de datos. Explico. Esta página que quiero hacer requiere de que el usuario ingrese su numero de telefono y una contraseña para ingresar. Entonces yo estuve probando como buscar el número de teléfono de un usuario en la colección que cree y para eso uso un método llamado findOne() que pasa como parámetro un json con el valor que intento localizar:

```
var a = Users.find({
      tel:7862627420
    })
    console.log(a.tel)
```

y luego lo intento mostrar por consola de esa manera. Esto me devuelve un valor undefined lo cual no quiero, sino mas bien que me devuelva el numero.

No se si me di a explicar bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que aunque mongo es `sincrono` Javascript y Nodejs no lo son así que el código que tienes no funciona por esa razón debes utilizar una función anónima como siguiente parámetro después del objeto que pasas para realizar la búsqueda, esta función es llamada `callback` y Nodejs y el `driver` que conecta a mongo con node funciona en con ellos.
La función `callback` como notación de Nodejs siempre debe obtener como primer parámetro un error y luego dependiendo la documentación de la función que se este utilisando x cantidad de datos, esto quiere decir que se retornara por medio de la funcion `callback` y no la función como tal.

```
//  mal nunca llegara a tener un valor a 
var a = Users.find({
  tel:7862627420
})
// como a no tiene nada entonces la propiedad tel no existe
console.log(a.tel)


// forma correcta
Users.find({ 
  tel:7862627420
}, function callback(error, a) {

// aquí si exite a
console.log(a)
})
```

Comment: Ahora entiendo. El primero hace uso del findOne() antes de cargar la base de datos. Eso veía en la consola pero no supe como solucionar ese problema. Gracias.

Comment: Las consultas a base de datos siempre son asícronas, por eso es necesario el uso de código asíncrono (como callbacks o promesas en Javascript)